# Нужна ли запятая перед "словно впервые"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Нужна ли запятая перед "словно впервые" в предложении "Они делали это словно впервые".
Изменится ли написание, если изменить предложение на "Они делали это словно в первый раз".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборот не обособляется: Они делали это **словно впервые**. Они делали это **словно в первый раз**.

Это оборот **со значением уподобления**, союзы "как, будто, словно" могут **примыкать** к любому члену предложения, для поверки их можно изъять из предложения (структура его при этом не изменится). Такие обороты **обычно не обособляются** (обособление возможно при распространенности или удобной позиции).

Примеры:

Я **словно проснулась** после недолгого счастливого сна. Но они существуют **словно на разных планетах**. **Словно по команде** они проходят сквозь строй препятствий.

Answer (score 3):

Они делали это словно впервые.-Запятой нет, т.к. нет сравнения. Делали как?- впервые. "Словно" здесь выполняет роль частицы "как будто", вносящей значение неуверенности. Во втором предложении то же самое.

Была  бы запятая, если б было: "Они делали это  **так**,словно впервые".

Answer (score 3):

"Словно впервые" и "словно в первый раз" по смыслу тесно связаны со сказуемым, поэтому запятая перед сравнительным союзом не ставится.

*Они делали это словно впервые. Они делали это словно в первый раз.*

**Не выделяются запятыми сравнительные обороты** с указанными союзами, **если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу**: ... *Мы с ним словно родные братья;  Стоит словно вкопанный; Огни фонарей  словно маяки.*[Оборот в составе сказуемого](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/)